# how diagnose csvsql "column not found" error

Tags: csvkit

Using csvkit on macOS 10.14.3

input file:

`head -n 3 Nov_git_v2.csv`

Model_var,dummy

Age,

Basket_Size_FP_24,

Basket_Size_FP_6,

```
csvsql --query "select Model_var from Nov_gift_v2"  Nov_gift_v2.csv
```

produces error:

sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: Model_var

`csvstat -c 1-2  Nov_gift_v2.csv > csvstat_output.txt`

displays the column "Model_var" and lists its properties, implying the column exists

```
csvsql --query "select Model_var from Nov_gift_v2"  Nov_gift_v2.csv
```

expected:

Age

Basket_Size_FP_24

Basket_Size_FP_6

actual output:

sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: Model_var

Comment: `  csvsql --query 'select "Model_var" from "Nov_gift_v2"' Nov_gift_v2.csv`
"""Model_var"""
Model_var
Model_var
Model_var

Comment: the query produces the output "Model_var Model_var Model_var"

Comment: Do you have Python 2 or 3?

Comment: python 2.7.16 on /usr/local/bin/python

Comment: but I see i also have python 3.7.2,which i installed...i don't remember installing 2.7, so I suspect that csvkit installed this as part of its installation, could this be so?

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem with csvsql 1.0.4. What's your version (`csvsql --version`)?

Try with

```
csvsql --query 'select "Model_var" from "Nov_gift_v2"'  Nov_gift_v2.csv
```

Comment: I'm on csvsql 1.0.3

Comment: @PatrickR for me it works. Could you share your file (not simply cut and paste here)?

Comment: what's the best way to upload the file ?  It's small (43 records, 1 field)

Comment: @PatrickR you could use databin (http://databin.pudo.org/) or gist (https://gist.github.com/).

Comment: @PatrickR as you can see in this image I have no error https://i.imgur.com/Y4Asbah.png The command I have used is `curl -sL "http://databin.pudo.org/t/6b64b2.csv" | csvsql --query 'select "Model_var" from stdin' | head`

Comment: OK, so the problem is not the data, it's something to do with the setup of csvkit and python 2.7?  do you know how i could make csvkit use by python 3.7.2 version?  How can i make python 3.7.2 my default version?

Comment: @PatrickR I'm not a mac user. You could do: uninstall csvkit, than install python 3 and pip, and than install csvkit via pip3 (`pip3 csvkit`). Here a tutorial about Python and pip 3 https://evansdianga.com/install-pip-osx/